# Primefaces datepicker in month-view

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datepicker

I'm having some troubles with the primefaces datepicker component when using `view="month"`. It's not possible to restrict the date selection to a certain month range, only to a year range. Also the month view setting does not work with dateTemplate (`dateTemplate="dateTemplateFunc"`). (The javascript function never gets called).
Does anybody know about a workaround to restrict the month-selection for example to 03/2017-06/2019 and to dynamically customise the background of the months while using `view="month"`?

Update: As Melloware suggested I created an MVCE for it:
https://github.com/BalthaZarr83/datePickerIssue

Comment: Is there any way you could create an MVCE using this project: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test to create the smallest reproducible example showing the problem?  If you can reproduce it I suggest attaching your MVCE to a PrimeFaces Issue.

Comment: Thank you! I will do that within the next days.

Comment: @Melloware: In case you're interested: I created the MVCE. See my update.

Comment: OK i would follow the Issue template and attach your MVCE to an issue ticket here: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues

Comment: @Melloware: Thanks for your help! I created the issue ticket.

Comment: Thanks I created a solution below for others.  Thank you so much for taking the time to create and MVCE and report it. You won't believe how many people refuse to do that but still expect us to solve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue reported: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5021

Fixed in PF 7.0.6 Elite and PF 7.1. with this commit: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/commit/204acbb11032b972cc640fcd7a19b72f77070969

Comment: Great! Thanks for your big help. Looking forward to 7.0.6:-)

Comment: I just checked out the latest PF Elite release and while the datetemplate function is called now in the monthview, it is still not possible to access the actual date for which it is called as only the monthshortname like 'jan' is being passed. But I would like to conditionally render the monthselection on whether the date is within a certain range.. Am I missing something?

Comment: I would create a more specific MVCE showing your exact issue and open another ticket.